# Javascript alert method is now working with one of the objects

Tags: javascript, properties, javascript-objects, alert

I'm currently a newbie in the field of front end dev. I made an object and tried to alert the value of one of its properties but when i tested, all alerts and prompts stopped working.

```js
// creating object in JavaScript
var person = {
  // Properties
  name = "John",
  age = 18,
  height = "5'11",
}

// accessing property of an object person
person.age() = 19; //is this the right way?
alert(person.age());
```

Comment: `person.age = 19` — the `()` is for calling functions, and your properties do not have functions as values.

Comment: `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer"` Not sure why you are using `=` inside of an object.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems here:

1. Use "`:`" instead of "`=`" when assigning values in a map
2. Don´t use `()` to access a property - simply use the property name. Use `()` if you want to access a method.

```js
// creating object in JavaScript
var person = {
  // Properties
  name: "John",
  age: 18,
  height: "5'11",
}

// accessing property of an object person
person.age = 19; 
alert(person.age);
```

Comment: not only when you want to "access" a method, but when you want to *execute* a method/function